# Matlab - get subplot rows and columns

Tags: matlab, resize, matlab-figure, subplot

I'm writing a script to resize any figure given to me, and I'd like to get the rows and columns of a subplot. For instance, if someone gave me a figure created by:

```
hfig = figure;
haxes = subplot(3,4,1);
...
```

Is there a property in the figure or axes handles that tells me that the figure has 3 rows and 4 columns? I need to resize each axis, and knowing the rows and columns is important so I know how to resize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such property. There is only `'Position'` property for axes object. What subplot function does is calculate proper axes position.

You can find all the axes on a figure with `ax = findobj(gcf,'type','axes');`. Then get positions with `get(ax,'position')` and analyze them for number of rows and columns.

For example:

```
pos = cell2mat(get(ax,'position'));
nrows = numel(unique(pos(:,2))); % the same Y position means the same row
ncols = numel(unique(pos(:,1))); % the same X position means the same column
```

Notice however that it will analyze only existing axes. If only two axes were created with `subplot(221)` and `subplot(222)` you will get 1 row, not 2.